# How to multiply gridview columns and display that in another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to multiply gridview columns consisting of one Label and Textbox control inside gridview and display the multiplied value in another column as shown in the figure. What i want to do is that once i clicked button all items are displayed on gridview as given below and then it will automatically multiply rate * 1 (by default Quantity is 1) in corresponding column.

My asp.net code

```
 <%--ServiceID --%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceID" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblServiceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceId")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<%-- Rate --%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Rate")%>' CssClass="rate"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>       
<ItemStyle Width="70px" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<%-- Quantity --%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="txtQty"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Gridview

[image]

C# Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text));
}
```

Comment: Although you could do this server side e.g. via Ajax and an UpdatePanel, because Total is derived, I would simply do this in JavaScript on the client side?

Comment: best and faster will be do it in javascript

Comment: I agree with both about doing it on client side using javascript but I would do it with jQuery which will do this in few statements.

Comment: are you using jQuery also?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hybrid client & server side approach, which minimizes Postbacks (i.e. no Ajax)

I've assumed you are binding an entity similar to: (Note that the initial value of `Total` is derived, server side)

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return Rate * Quantity; }
    }
}
```

On the `.aspx`, you'll want to render the initial state of both `Quantity` and `Total` (e.g. the same page may be needed for editing existing rows). Note that the `Total` label is server bound, but needs no `input` control since its value is derived. Total will not be posted back to the server.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceID" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblServiceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceId")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Rate")%>' CssClass="rate"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="txtQty" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" CssClass='Total'><%# Eval("Total")%></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

To the same .aspx page, add the following javascript to do client side calculation of the `Total`, triggered on a change of any Quantity. (and ensure that you have [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) already referenced)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.txtQty').on('change', function (evt) {
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
            var rate = Number($row.find('.rate').text());
            var qty = Number($(this).val());
            var total = rate * qty;
            $row.find('.Total').text(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this case, because the calculation is a simple multiplication, duplication of the total calculation on both server and client side can be justified, since this saves wasted IO. However, if the calculation was much more complicated (e.g. Tax, Discounts, Interest penalties etc) then I would suggest keeping the calculation entirely server side, and then Ajaxing the parameters to the `onChange` to the server via an UpdatePanel (or preferably a Json / REST API) service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are strictly want to do it at the server side because of other calculations or security reasons, then you have to loop through all rows and then find the `label` and `textbox` controls from the `gridview` and then you can update the value.

```
    foreach(GridviewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label total = ((Label)Row.FindControl("lblTotal"));
            Label rate = ((Label)Row.FindControl("lblRate"));
            TextBox quantity = ((TextBox)Row.FindControl("txtQuantity"));
            if(rate != null && quantity != null)
            {
                 total.Text = (int.Parse(rate.Text) * int.Parse(quantity.Text)).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really very simple: don't do it.

Calculate all of your data ahead of time, then bind your GridView to the data. This may mean that you have to add a column to the underlying data source, whether in the code behind, or in the database. Then calculate the value of the added column, and finally just bind your GridView to the complete data source.

The GridView control is for displaying and editing data, not for calculating data.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(GridviewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int quantity= 1;
            TextBox txtQuantity = ((TextBox)Row.FindControl("txtQuantity"));
            int.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text,out quantity);
            Label lblRate = ((Label)Row.FindControl("lblRate"));

            decimal total = decimal.Parse(lblRate.Text) * quantity;
            Label lblTotal = ((Label)Row.FindControl("lblTotal"));

            lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to multiply grid view columns, display that in another column, then sum up that specific column to get total value

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        function validateTextBox() {
            ValidateCheckBox()
            //get target base & child control.
            var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%=this.gv1.ClientID%>');
            var TargetChildControl1 = "text1";

            //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
            var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
                if (Inputs[n].type == 'text' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl1, 0) >= 0)
                    if (Inputs[n].value != "") return true;
            alert('Enter some value in textbox!');
            return false;
        }
        function ValidateCheckBox() {            
            //get target base & child control.
            var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%=this.gv1.ClientID%>');
           var TargetChildControl = "check1";    //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
           var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
           for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
               if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0)
                   if (Inputs[n].checked) return true;
           alert('Select at least one checkbox!');
           return false;
       }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div>
       <center>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            runat="server" Height="115px" Width="373px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
         <Columns>             
             <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>             
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductId" DataField="ProductId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductId" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductName" DataField="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enter Quantity">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>    
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltotal1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>  
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>              
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BaviConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductId], [ProductName], [Price] FROM [Product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="javascript:return validateTextBox();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </center>
                <br />
                <br />

    <center>
    <h><strong><span class="auto-style1">Selected Product</span><br />
    </strong></h>
        &nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="gv2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" >
        <Columns>  
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductName" DataField="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />      
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" DataField="Total" SortExpression="Total" />       
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Total Price" ></asp:Label>         
    <asp:TextBox ID="txttotal" runat="server" Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
    </center>

            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] {
        new DataColumn("ProductName"),
        new DataColumn("Price"),
        new DataColumn("Quantity"),
        new DataColumn("total")
    });

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            CheckBox chk = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("check1") as CheckBox);
            string qty = ((TextBox)gv1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("text1")).Text;[enter image description here][1]

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                string name = row.Cells[2].Text;
                string Price = row.Cells[3].Text;
                string Quantity = qty;                  
                ((Label)gv1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbltotal1")).Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(qty) * Convert.ToInt32(Price));
                string Ttl = ((Label)gv1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbltotal1")).Text;
                tprice += int.Parse(Ttl);
                dt.Rows.Add(name, Price, Quantity, Ttl);
            }

        }

    }
    txttotal.Text = tprice.ToString();
    gv2.DataSource = dt;
    gv2.DataBind();

}
```

[this will the final output[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IHx0.png)